# GNUPLOT: boxplots variable line style/colors

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I have multiple data files for which I want to draw a single figure. Each of the files contains a column with two variables: true and false. I would like to draw boxplot for each of these values such that they can be compared. Sample of data file is given below:

```
0.6,true
0.7,true
0.5,false
0.4,true
..
```

I come up with following code:

```
plot inputFile1 using (1):($4):(0.3):3  title 'A' , \
inputFile2 using (3):($4):(0.3):3   title 'B'
```

This generated the following figure: [image]

However, I would like to customize it such that all the boxplots with "true" variable have one specific line style/color and boxplots with "false" variable have another specific line style/color. 
Furthermore, I would like to show in the title the shape of true and false, however, on x-xis, I want to have File A and B for each true,false pair.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

With your current datafile, you would need to detect whether the second column contains `true` or `false` and act accordingly. However, I am not sure `gnuplot` can process strings from a datafile.

If you process your file and replace the `true` or `false` by 1 or 0, then you can adapt the following line:

```
plot [0:6] "+" using 0:($0/2.):(0.3):0:xtic((int($0)%2)==0?"true":"false") w errorb lc variable
```

Here the 4th number in the `using` list defines the colour, with `$0` the colour changes for each line of the file, but if the colour number is in one column of your file then use that column. Replace the "+" by your file and the first two numbers in `using` by the parameters needed by your plotting style. The `xtic` command processes some column in the file (here the line number `$0`) and labels the x tic depending on the value (see `help ternary`).

*Note that your MWE does not work as is, please amend it if you want a more precise answer.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please like to explain it especially this "[0:6] "+" using 0:($0/2.):(0.3):0:xtic" ?

Comment: that's done, remember to give a working MWE if you want more detailed answers.